# how to kill/reset a running jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a slideshow plugin which works fine. Alone...

I have 3 different buttons on one page. They all call the same jQuery slideshow plugin and load the slideshow with different images into the same divider (with id="slideshow")

I remove the slideshow and it's elements from the #slideshow every single time before I load the new slideshow with the new images.

It would all work fine except that the more times I click on the buttons the messier the whole thing gets because the plugin is opened every single time and the plugin gets confused which images to show.

My question is. How can I completely kill a running plugin so the new one can load from the beginning. I tried empty(), die(), remove(), detach() APIs without successs.

Is there any other way?

Thanks.

http://muttley.freewebspace.com/slideshow/

Comment: This totally depends on the plugin implementation. You should also investigate which remains are left after you *remove* your plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a common way to destroy plugins on an element, if the plugin itself doesn't support it. You will probably have to remove the element you actually called the plugin on and create it again:

```
var oldDiv = $('#slideshow');
var parent = oldDiv.parent();
oldDiv.remove();
parent.append($('<div>').attr('id', 'slideshow'));
// Initialize slideshow here again

// Untested but shorter way:
$('#slideshow').replaceWith($('<div>').attr('id', 'slideshow'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Meanwhile I managed to put it on so it can be seen what I'm talking about.
http://muttley.freewebspace.com/slideshow/

Comment: I cannot use this because I load the image list from another file in a div id="slideshow". If you check this site and the source muttley.freewebspace.com/slideshow it can be seen what I'm talking about. I found a weird solution. I figured if I pause the slideshow before I hit another slideshow button it works ok. Do you think it is possible to call the stopAutoplay() from the plugin somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the plugin. Does this plugin support multiple slideshows on a page? If so, instead of removing the contents of `#slideshow`, perhaps it will work bette rif you replace `#slideshow` itself with a new element.