# restart a javascript slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have implemented s3slider in a jquery-ui tabs.  The multiple sliders operate fine. I added an onClick to the tab so the slideshow would begin at the beginning when you clicked the tab, but, to my surprise I have a copy of the slider in the tab. I thought that the object might be reset if I called the slider again but no go. I have a [jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/D7QBc/)

The code is too long to list fully here but the js including the plugin seem very straight forward. The plugin code needs a .Die() or similar but I dont know how to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $('#slider').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 4000
        });
    });

    function PreFire() {
        slider1 = $('#slider1').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 3000
        });
    }
```

You can duplicate the results in chrome and IE9 click through the tabs. On the third click you have at least one additional copy of the slider. All I want to do is restart the slideshow. I have tried the 'current' parameter with the same results.

Before you slam me for a dupe: I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122840/how-to-kill-reset-a-running-jquery-plugin) but that did not work in my case. The images just disappeared.

Comment: I have given up on the S3slider plugin. I am using the jquery cycle plugin and creating the effects I wanted with that.  The plugin has a richer API and includes a 'destroy' command.